# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{k+\alpha-1}\text{e}^{-(\beta+1)\lambda} \, d\lambda$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

This definite integral relates to Bayesian statistics and is a problem that needs to be solved in order to show that the $\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution is a (prior) conjugate family for the $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ distribution. Now, I know there are ways to prove this by means of proportionality arguments, and then identify the posterior distribution to make the necessary conclusion, but I want to do it the hard (but more intuitive) way. So I have,

$$
\int_0^\infty \lambda^{k+\alpha-1}\text{e}^{-(\beta+1) \lambda} \, d\lambda
$$

where $k$ is an integer $\geq0$ and $\alpha, \beta > 0$. In a "normal" situation where $\lambda$ is raised to the power of an integer, I would be able to solve it by integration of parts, but know I am not so sure. Any clues?

**Edit**

I use the hints user NHL provided:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \lambda^{k+\alpha-1}\text{e}^{-(\beta+1)\lambda} \, d\lambda &= \big\{\mu = (\beta+1)\lambda,\, d\mu = (\beta+1) \, d\lambda \big\} \\[3mm]&= \frac{1}{(\beta + 1)^{k+\alpha}} \int_0^\infty \mu^{k+\alpha-1} \text{e}^{-\mu} \, d\mu \\[3mm] &= \big\{ \Gamma(z)\triangleq \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{z-1}\text{e}^{-x} \, dx\big\}\\[3mm] &= \frac{\Gamma(k+\alpha)}{(\beta + 1)^{k+\alpha}}.
\end{align}

Comment: even if $\lambda$ is raised to a non-integer power, the integration by part works the same

Comment: So how do we solve for instance $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{0.5}\text{e}^{-\lambda}d\lambda$$ with integration by parts? @NHL

Comment: $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{0.5}\text{e}^{-\lambda}d\lambda= [-\lambda^{0.5}e^{-\lambda}]_0^\infty+0.5\int_0^\infty \lambda^{-0.5}e^{-\lambda}$. so you get $\Gamma(0.5)=0.5\Gamma(-0.5)$

Comment: Is that the definition of the gamma function? I see! How about this case: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{0.5}\text{e}^{-2\lambda}$$ where we cannot use the definition directly. Is it still possible? @NHL

Comment: You can use a change of variable $\mu=2\lambda $ to get to the definition of the gamma function

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: if you have an answer (even one of your own) then post it as such and check it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you just trying to evaluate the integral? $\qquad$

Comment: @NHL :  $$ \begin{align} & \int_0^\infty \lambda^{0.5} e^{-2\lambda} \, d\lambda \\ {} \\ = {} & \int_0^\infty \left( \tfrac \mu 2 \right)^{1.5-1} e^{-\mu} \,  \left( \tfrac{d\mu} 2 \right) \\ {} \\ = {} & \frac 1 {2^{1.5}} \int_0^\infty \mu^{1.5-1} e^{-\mu} \, d\mu \\ {} \\ = {} & \frac 1 {2^{1.5}} \Gamma(1.5) = \frac{ 0.5\sqrt\pi }{2^{1.5}}. \end{align} $$

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find an explicit expression for the integral. See my answer below, we solved it. Thank you for your help! @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 1):

I use the hints user NHL provided:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{k+\alpha-1}\text{e}^{-(\beta+1)\lambda}d\lambda &= \big\{\mu = (\beta+1)\lambda,\; d\mu = (\beta+1)d\lambda\big\} \\[3mm]&= \frac{1}{(\beta + 1)^{k+\alpha}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu^{k+\alpha-1}\text{e}^{-\mu}d\mu \\[3mm] &= \big\{ \Gamma(z)\triangleq \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{z-1}\text{e}^{-x}dx\big\}\\[3mm] &= \frac{\Gamma(k+\alpha)}{(\beta + 1)^{k+\alpha}}.
\end{align}