# $\int_0^{+ \infty} \dfrac{1}{ x^{ 1 + \alpha}} e^{ - \lambda x} = \lambda^{\alpha} \Gamma( - \alpha)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

- $\lambda >0$
- $\alpha <0$
- $ h(x)= \dfrac{1}{ x^{ 1 + \alpha}} e^{ - \lambda x}$
- We want to compute $\int_0^{+ \infty} h(x)$

The result is of interest for the study of a [particular Poisson process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201910/a-particular-poisson-compound-process-with-drift).

---

It looks like a [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) or this [computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013588/compute-int-0-infty-lambdak-alpha-1-texte-beta1-lambda-d).
I do $u =\lambda x$ , and the integral $I$

$I= \lambda^{\alpha} \Gamma( - \alpha)$ with  $\alpha <0$

Comment: Do you know the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)?

Comment: Thanks, I found a result. It is correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\ {\mathrm d}}$Since you have already found the result based on my comment, I'll just answer this for completion.

We have the integral $$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1 + \alpha}} e^{-\lambda x} \d x. \tag{1}$$
(You had not written the $\d x$ but I assume that $x$ is your variable of integration from the context.)

Since $\lambda > 0$, the substitution $\lambda x = u$ in $(1)$ gives us
$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^{1 + \alpha}}{u^{1 + \alpha}} e^{-u} \frac{1}{\lambda} \d u.$$
This is simplified to
$$I = \lambda^{\alpha}\int_0^\infty u^{-\alpha - 1} e^{-u} \d u.$$
Since $\alpha < 0$, the integral above is simply the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) evaluated at $-\alpha$. In other words, $$I = \lambda^\alpha \Gamma(-\alpha).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^\infty x^{-(1+\alpha)}e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$$
let $t=\lambda x\Rightarrow dx=dt/\lambda$ and so you get:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac t\lambda\right)^{-(1+\alpha)}e^{-t}\frac{dt}{\lambda}$$
so for the function we get $t^{-(1+\alpha)}e^{-t}$ and bringing all the lambdas together we get:
$$\lambda^{-1}\lambda^{(1+\alpha)}=\lambda^\alpha$$
and so we are left with:
$$I=\lambda^\alpha\int_0^\infty t^{-(1+\alpha)}e^{-t}\,dt$$
and recalling the definition of the gamma function:
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt\tag{Gamma}$$
we can conclude:
$$I=\lambda^\alpha\Gamma(-\alpha)$$